# iOS - Application crashes on startup, possibly killed by runtime

Tags: ios

we have a problem with two devices, namely iPhone 4s and iPad 2. The application works perfectly on all other supported devices, but when distributed through add hoc or enterprise account, simply crashes on startup before any calls from UIApplication delegate.

Is there any way to debug this behaviour or to get any meaningful message we can work with. Fabric/Crashlitics or Hockey app we use for distribution does not return any message about crash.

Is there also any way to get a description about why/if the runtime killed the application?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a hold of one of those devices where the crashes are happening, you could connect them to your Xcode and take a look at the latest crash logs, sorted by date. There should be a stack trace that could point towards the problem.

But since you're not getting anything from Fabric, makes it look like you are in the right track that the application might be taking too long to load (specially on those older devices).

If those devices run fine when attached to xcode (in a debug session) you're right about the issue. iOS only kills your app when it takes too long to launch if you are **not** in a debug session.

Regarding the issue itself, try to use Instruments and see if there're big chunks of work being done in the main thread when the app launches.

Also review:

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

See if there's something you can dispatch on a background thread.